Как связать разные языки программирования? (Добавить скриптовый язык))
Всем привет, хочу разобраться с тем, как связываются языки. В пример приведу движок Godot, написан на С++, а скрипты можно писать на встроенном языке и на С#. Пример чисто показушный, дабы было легче понять вопрос. И мне вот интересно, как это все работает, как например в код С++ попадают данные из С#. Насколько сложно реализовать это и есть ли какие-то учебники/гайды/пособия и все с этим связанное, чтобы более подробно изучить вопрос?
P.S. Например, есть у меня базовый код для C++:
int main()
{
   return 0;
}

И есть код на C#:
public class Player
{
   private double _brainSize = 0;
   public Player() {}
   
   public GetBrainSize() => _brainSize;
}

Как мне на С++, создать класс Player из C# и работать с ним, изменять поля объекта класса в рантайме и другое. По типу
#include <C#> // Чисто символично

int main()
{
   Player* p1 = new Player();
   return 0;
}


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

ну можете посмотреть как это сделано для Lua

Для связывания C++ и ,Net (включая C#) создали специальный язык C++CLI.  Еще есть варианты: промежуточный интерфейс в стиле C (без плюсов), или технология COM.

самый простой [и всегда работающий способ] - разделите процессы; это значит, что в простейшем случае есть процесс обслуживающий что-то, и есть другой процесс обслуживающий что-то другое, и эти два процесса написаны на принципиально отличающихся вещах; так вот в простейшем случае можно запустить пару процессов и устроить между ними межпроцессовое взаимодействие; иначе говоря куски ПО могут быть написаны на разных исполняющих средах, и [в простейшем случае] ничего в этом страшного - нет; т.е. можете запустить java-машину, дот-нет-машину, скриптовую машину и они будут вертеться в разных процессах

в реальности, максимально встреченная степень такого "безумия" [впрочем, если это нужно - то почему бы и нет?] - составляла 17 процессов, где были встречены жаба-куски, фортран-куски, питон-куски, дот-нет-куски, естественно скюель-куски, и вроде бы всё) но это не точно

языки - никак не связываются, потому что чаще всего связываются исполняющие среды - и это тру; потому что эмулировать исполняющую среду через другую исполняющую среду в рамках одного процесса - вот этого делать не нужно, потому что получится всегда [иногда сильно] хуже, чем в оригинале

банальный пример: кто-то написал выше про плюсики и шарпики, и тут уже есть грандиозная проблема; и она ровно следующая: исполняющая среда управляемого дот-нета заточена на объекты, и с точки зрения дот-нета - сам дот-нет управляет объектами - и вмешиваться в это - нужно крайне аккуратно, иначе всё мгновенно превращается в тыкву; а допустим что-то накарченное на плюсиках неаккуратно пробрасывается в управляемый дот-нет, и вот тут и наступит карачун управляемого рантайма, т.е. в случае неаккуратного действия одного на другое - мгновенно теряется эффективность и первого и второго

Не стоит заморачиваться с таким подходом. Вместо этого напишите интерпретатор "сетевых" объектов и специфицируйте протокол обмена сообщениями (лучше текстовыми (например, tcl тут волне сгодится (кстати, сообщения на нем могут прямо интерпретироваться объектами, если добавить к ним интерпретатор tcl (существует в виде библиотеки на Си)))) между ними. При некотором обобщении имен объектов вы сможете при таком подходе строить даже распределенную по сети систему вычислений
